# Cant seen to find the change in gcc13.2 release notes or error: invalid redeclaration of template<typename> with different constraints

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, compiler-bug

I had the following issue a couple of days ago when using arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain on arch linux, which uses gcc13.2 as the gcc version, unlike the toolchain I was using in Ubuntu, I assumed it would be some version stuff so I went to the gcc release page to read the notes: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-13/changes.html, but as you will see nothing about redeclaration of templates is mentioned

upon some research I came to this reproducible example:

```
// compiles fine under gcc 12.3

#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

 template<typename T>
 class Sensor{
   public:
    int read();
  };

template<typename T>
  requires std::is_integral_v<T>
int Sensor<T>::read(){
 return 1;
}

int main(){
 Sensor<int>  s;
 s.read();
}


//does not compile under gcc 13.2
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>

class Sensor{
 public:
    int read();
};

template<typename T>
 requires std::is_integral_v<T>
int Sensor<T>::read(){
 return 1;
}

int main(){
 Sensor<int>  s;
 s.read();
}
```

Could someone explain why in version 12.3 it is allowed but not in 13.2?
Also I'd assume the constrainst enforced in 13.2 should have been a standard *de facto way* ago

Comment: Whatever code and compiler output you want to ask about should be presented in the question itself.  Links to external sites are not acceptable for this purpose. If you're asking about a specific change mentioned in the release notes, then a quotation of the relevant note should be presented in the question too.

Comment: The compiler options you are using are also relevant.

Comment: You can see the options in godbolt, all three cases take the same parameter, -std=c++20

Comment: @Mrmudkip Questions on Stack Overflow need to be self-contained. Godbolt is really great as a supplement, but this question needs to be understandable and answerable even if that link breaks. Can you copy the relevant [mre] into the question as formatted code?

Comment: You have not mentioned once what is "it" you are talking about.

Comment: edited the question to show it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant note is in [`gcc/cp/ChangeLog`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/ChangeLog):

```
2023-03-14  Patrick Palka  <...>

        PR c++/96830
        * pt.cc (push_inline_template_parms_recursive): Set
        TEMPLATE_PARMS_CONSTRAINTS.
        (push_template_decl): For an out-of-line declaration, verify
        constraints for each enclosing template scope match those of the
        original template declaratation.


    gcc/testsuite/ChangeLog:

            * g++.dg/cpp2a/concepts-class5.C: New test.
            * g++.dg/cpp2a/concepts-class5a.C: New test.
```

> Could someone explain why in version 12.3 it is allowed but not in 13.2?

12.3 was released before this bugfix was submitted.

---

The full commit message is:

```
commit cd5baeb4489b6a953abbc7f02fea457fd9ed2f83
Author: Patrick Palka <...>
Date:   Tue Mar 14 19:14:29 2023 -0400

    c++: redeclaring member of constrained class template [PR96830]

    An out-of-line definition of a member of a constrained class template
    needs to repeat the template's constraints, but it turns out we don't
    verify anywhere that the two sets of constraints match.  This patch
    adds such a check to push_template_decl, nearby a similar consistency
    check for the template parameter list lengths.

            PR c++/96830

    gcc/cp/ChangeLog:

            * pt.cc (push_inline_template_parms_recursive): Set
            TEMPLATE_PARMS_CONSTRAINTS.
            (push_template_decl): For an out-of-line declaration, verify
            constraints for each enclosing template scope match those of the
            original template declaratation.

    gcc/testsuite/ChangeLog:

            * g++.dg/cpp2a/concepts-class5.C: New test.
            * g++.dg/cpp2a/concepts-class5a.C: New test.
```

Comment: it is interesting that C++20 is supported since gcc9 and yet this wasn't found/addressed until now :))

Comment: @Mrmudkip C++ is tricky. All compilers have bugs :-)